Holomorphic one form and its association to Minimal surface
I am new to studying holomorphic one form. While studying minimal surface, it is written that in The Weierstrass-Enneper Representation $\mathbf{X}(z)=\Re\int \left( \frac{1}{2} (1 - g^2) \, dh, \frac{i}{2} (1 + g^2) \, dh, g \, dh \right)$  the $dh$ is defined to be the holomorphic form . Can anyone please give a detail explanation. 
Edit: I need to understand how to visualize the holomorphic form in this particular representation and why it is essential here .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
